# How to await for firestore database to fetch data before returning it

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the Firestore database and need to fetch some data from it. How do I make the function await for the data before returning the list?

```
fun getExercise(bodyPart: String): MutableList<String> {
        val db = Firebase.firestore
        val exercisesList = mutableListOf<String>()

        val exercise = db.collection("exercises")
        val query = exercise.whereEqualTo("body-part", bodyPart)
        query.get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            for(temp in result) {
                exercisesList.add(temp.id)
                Log.d(TAG, "${temp.id} => ${temp.data}")
            }
        }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)
            }

        return exercisesList

}
```

I know I need to use `.await()` but I am new to Kotlin and can't make it work.

Comment: Aside from Rosário's excellent answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudFirestore/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see 2 possible options:

##### 1. Change your code in order to call another function with the result instead of returning the result

```kotlin
fun getExercise(bodyPart: String) {
        val db = Firebase.firestore
        val exercisesList = mutableListOf<String>()

        val exercise = db.collection("exercises")
        val query = exercise.whereEqualTo("body-part", bodyPart)
        query.get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            for(temp in result) {
                exercisesList.add(temp.id)
                Log.d(TAG, "${temp.id} => ${temp.data}")
            }
            // Call another function with the result:
            anotherFunction(exercisesList)
        }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)
        }
}
```

##### 2. Implement Kotlin Coroutines

This option might be a little more complex than the first one for someone who's new to the language, as you'd need to understand the concept of [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html).

1. Start by adding the Coroutines dependency to your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9'
}
```

2. Change your function to become a `suspend` function:

```kotlin
suspend fun getExercise(bodyPart: String): MutableList<String> {
// ...
}
```

3. Use the `await()` extension function to fetch the result:

```kotlin
suspend fun getExercise(bodyPart: String): MutableList<String> {
    val db = Firebase.firestore
    val exercisesList = mutableListOf<String>()

    val exercise = db.collection("exercises")
    val query = exercise.whereEqualTo("body-part", bodyPart)

    try {
        val result = query.get().await()
        for (temp in result) {
            exercisesList.add(temp.id)
            Log.d(TAG, "${temp.id} => ${temp.data}")
        }

        return exercisesList
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)

        return emptyList() // returning an empty list in case the fetch fails
    }
}
```

4. Use a Coroutine scope when making a call to your `suspend` function:

```kotlin
// If you're calling from an Activity/Fragment, you can use the
// lifecycleScope from the lifecycle-runtime-ktx library
//
// If you're calling from a ViewModel, consider using the
// viewModelScope from the lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx library
//
// See https://d.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#dependencies
// for more details
lifecycleScope.launch { // Coroutine Scope
    val exercises: MutableList<String> = getExercise("arms")
    // use the list
}
```

More resources:

- [Coroutines on Android](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines)
- [How to use Kotlin Coroutines with Firebase APIs Youtube Short](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/9GvJ0OAOmo4)

Comment: i think you need to use with context coroutine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I implemented it with the coroutines and it works.